# Where can I find the names of the vessels in Titan AE?

Tags: titan-a-e

I would like to know the sources of the names of the vessels in *Titan AE*, besides the *Titan*.

The [Don Bluth Wiki](http://donbluth.wikia.com/wiki/Titan_A.E.) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_A.E.) both say that Korso's ship is the *Valkyrie*, and the repaired ship Cale and Akima fly is called the *Phoenix*, but I don't recall those names being used at all in the film (or in the captions/subtitles).

Where can I find a source for these names, supposing they're accurate?

I know that the names of those two ships can be found on the toys (see below), but I can't find any other sources. I'd also be interested in the name of the ship Cale originally escaped Earth's destruction in, if a source for that exists.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh, just [saw that there's an official novelization](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/102129/31178). @Richard sense tingling!

Comment: You know me so well. That being said, I'm still trying to get hold of the film screenplay and one of the graphic novels (Akima's Story)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're confirmed in the [official novelisation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0441007368)

> ***Akima waited in the Valkyrie's cockpit***, already feeling as if her
>   razor edge was starting to go dull. It didn't take long when you were
>   sitting in dock to get itchy.

and

> ***Phoenix was the name of the vessel.*** Cale did some checking and found
>   out that the Phoenix was a mythological bird that was reborn from the
>   ashes....
>
> *Perfect.*

and in the [movie's script](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=titan-a-e)

> **Corso:** *"This is the Valkyrie,not a singles bar. We're done."*

---

Gary Goldman, in a [promotional interview](http://www.geocities.ws/not_quite_paradise/interview_garygoldman.txt) confirmed the names of the two ships. Note that the transcriber has mistyped Valkyrie as Valkarie. I've also been unable to source the original interview so please treat this as *potentially* fan-written:

> **Goldman:** *Yeah. It's not so bad, I think, with the way we mix it. We
>   let it just self-support. It doesn't get in your face. There's only
>   two songs that get in your face, and that's the one that is when they
>   rebuild the Phoenix. The song by Lit is "I'm In Over My Head". And
>   when you first see Cale as a 19 year old, and he's working in the
>   salvage dump at Tau-14, there's a song there that, I'm trying to think
>   of the name of it, I think it's called....*

and

> **Goldman:** *The Titan design was done before Don and I took it. It wasn't
>   done as a computer element yet, but we had all the drawings that had
>   been approved by the Fox executives, and the Valkarie had been
>   designed. Those two main ships were designed. There were some rough
>   approvals on Akima, but we redesigned her somewhat. Korso wasn't
>   approved yet and Cale wasn't approved yet. There were some rough
>   concepts that were close on Gune, and definitely on Preed. But all of
>   it were drawings. There was no animation, per se, there was no
>   layouts. I'd say there was a good 3000 pieces of art that had gone
>   through in pre-production, but only a few things had been approved.*

and the original box-art has "the Valkyrie" printed on it

[image]

And of course we actually see the name of the Phoenix in the film

[image]

---

Purely as a matter of interest, there's some concept art [here](http://willmakra.com/featurefilm/) indicating that the original working name for the vessel was "The *Feenics*". I suspect this was intended humourously.

You can also see concepts for three other vessels that appeared in the opening "escape from Earth" sequence; The Vanguard, The Longbow and The Guardian.

Comment: I just rewatched the beginning, and I actually think "The Guardian" is the name of the escape vessel at the beginning, based on the design. It has 3 rounded engines,  forming a Y-pattern when seen from behind! Thanks so much for that find! Also, the Vanguard design matches the rest of the escape fleet.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I'm pretty sure the concept artist you linked just misspelled "Phoenix" phonetically (phoenetically!?), but I'm going to call those other ships Guardian and Vanguard in my head (and if I build the LEGO versions that I'm planning.)

Comment: If a thing is worth doing, it's worth doing with massive overkill